# How can I contain epoxy while it sets up?

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture, epoxy

So I finally built my portable home bar but I would like to have a bottle cap bar top with epoxy coating. However, I do not want to add wooden edges to contain the epoxy when I pour it over the bottle caps because of the wooden molding design that is already present. So what would be the most effective way to contain the epoxy when pouring? If any members have bar-building experience either at home or for commercial "alcohol-serving" establishments, thoughts and comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have built a few and I used casting resin.  i got it from a fiberglass boat builder. it set up very fast but is self leveling.  we let it drip off the sides and cleaned up the edges after it cured with a router and 440 and 1600 paper.  I have encased fishing lures, German coasters etc.  it cures hard as stone and very transparent.  It has to be poured monolithic and quickly.  We use plastic non stick auto body tools to move it around. The results are incredible. Like a 1/4 inch of glass.

Comment: How much did the casting resin cost?

Comment: Seems I remember it was around $90 a gal. I got it threw a relative at Sabre Yachts at a discount.

Answer (score 3):

Backyard boatbuilders often work with epoxy and polyester resin like Mr. Homes mentions. Saran Wrap and waxed paper are popular and common materials for creating surfaces for containing these resins. Masking tape will not be easily removed.

When selecting your resin, keep in mind that you may have some control over how fast it sets. Some resins are made to set more quickly than others. Some polyester resins can be made to set more quickly or slowly depending on how much catalyst you add. All resins take time to set completely; they may get hard to the touch in 20 minutes to several hours, but they will take several days to reach complete and ultimate hardness.

If you haven't worked with it before, it can be a real advantage to have it set more slowly, giving you time to get it properly in place. Also be aware that resins that set very quickly can generate lots of heat, and the thicker the application the more heat there will be.

Note that the resin does not "dry", it undergoes a chemical reaction, so it doesn't change size. If you pour it level with your moulding, it will stay level when its set.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using electrical tape. I have successfully used electrical tape a multitude of times as a "cusp" around glass capillary tubing. The tape peels off easily after the epoxy has set

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually done this sort of top - I grew out of love with the idea before I got around to making one. I have seen descriptions of building a temporary edge with wide masking tape. You might want to reinforce that with a band clamp.

Of course, the little metal bottle caps are supposed to be nailed upside down on the floor, to give you the sensation of walking on little metal bottle caps nailed upside down to the floor. Don't forget the coracle painted in stripes of Telephone Black and White White to serve as a guitar tidy for parties. *(Flanders and Swann, who are terribly House and Garden at #7B - of course.)*